# Interpretation of comparation of two dependent variables which have identical values

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, interpretation

In theory I know statistical terms such as median, arithmetic mean, hi-square, etc., but how to interpret these terms if they are numbers like in the example. what does that mean ?

```
> summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = var1 ~ var2, data = data)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-7.119e-13 -1.680e-14 -1.630e-14 -1.630e-14  3.034e-11 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       3.179e-13  1.867e-14 1.702e+01   <2e-16 ***
var2              1.000e+00  4.098e-16 2.440e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

What is on 1779 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 5.954e+30 on 1 and 1779 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: You seem to have a perfect fit; with the returned parameter values, it would seem that var1 is identical to var2. Most of the numbers you see in the summary have no meaning if you have a perfect fit. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake specifying var1 and var2?

Comment: @wiwh Thank you for your comment, yes I have perfect fit. I thought I was doing something wrong but obviously these are numbers for perfect fit. :)